# XSLT. Move all nodes of specific type into one node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have an XML (number of `folder` and `file` nodes can vary):

```
<root>
  <system>3</system>
  <type>0</type>
  <file name="a"/>
  <folder name="aaa">
    <file name="b"/>
    <file name="c"/>
    <folder name="bbb">
      <file name="d"/>
      ...
    </folder>
    <folder name="ccc">
      <file name="e"/>
      ...
    </folder>
    ...
  </folder>
  ...
</root>
```

Should be converted into:

```
<root>
  <system>3</system>
  <type>0</type>
  <folder name="all_files">
    <file name="a"/>
    <file name="b"/>
    <file name="c"/>
    ...
  </folder>
</root>
```

I need to do it using XSLT, but I have a problem that I do not know how to copy `file` nodes into (`<folder name="all_files">`) node.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Where did you get `<file name="b"/>`? It is not in your input. And why are only some `file` nodes copied from the input to the output? And what "specific `(files)` node" are you talking about? I see no `files` node in your input nor in the output

Comment: @michael.hor257k all files are copied, `specific (files) node` is `<folder name="all_files">`, fixed that. Either `b` file is in the source example

Comment: @michael.hor257k basically what i need to do is to copy all `file` nodes into one `folder` node

Comment: @michael.hor257k Because i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//system | //type" mode="copy" />
        <folder name="all_files">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//file" mode="copy" />
        </folder>
    </root>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Applied to your input XML, following output is generated:

```
<root>
  <system>3</system>
  <type>0</type>
  <folder name="all_files">
    <file>a</file>
    <file>b</file>
    <file>c</file>
    <file>d</file>
    <file>e</file>
  </folder>
</root>
```

The template matching the root level applies templates to the `system` and `type` nodes with the mode `copy` (to prevent copying all nodes with the template matching all nodes and attributes).
Then, wrapped in the `<folder name="all_files">`, the same template is applied to all `file` nodes.

Saved [Demo](http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaFw) for this transformation.